# Webpack - Add asset to stats

Tags: plugins, webpack-2, babeljs

I'm still kinda new to building Webpack plugins, so I have a question on regarding how to proper add assets to the compilation.

I am building this plugin: [rebabel-webpack-plugin](https://www.github.com/tokimon/rebabel-webpack-plugin)
That in all its simplicity takes the compiled files and recompiles them again with babel to transpile them in to fx ES 5 compatable files (I know... it seems weird... The why is in the projects readme).

This actually works pretty well, but my assets are not showing up in the `Stats` part of webpack (eg. `compiler.getStats()`)

I am adding my recompiled assets to the `compilation.assets` list, but only my initial entry files and a dynamic named chunk shows up in the stats object.

So how do I make my recompiled assests show up in webpacks `stats` section?

Answer (score 0):

So after some digging around I think I found a solution to my problem.
It seems that I needed to add my newly created assets as chunks as well and change the names of the file references in there.

So the following code seems to solve the problem:

```
function addPrefixToFile(prefix, file) {
  return file.replace(/(^|[/\\])([^/\\]+)$/, `$1${prefix}$2`);
}

const files = chunks.reduce((arr, chunk) => {
  if(!chunk.rendered) { return arr; }

  // Create chunk copy
  const copy = Object.assign(Object.create(chunk), {
    name: chunk.name ? `${prefix}${chunk.name}` : chunk.name,
    files: (chunk.files || []).map((file) => addPrefixToFile(file)),
    parents: chunk.parents.map(
      (parent) => Object.assign({}, parent, {
        files: (parent.files || []).map((file) => addPrefixToFile(file))
      })
    )
  });

  chunkCopies.push(copy);
}, []);

// ... further down the line ...
chunks.push(...chunkCopies);
```

To me it seems a bit hacky so I was wondering if there is a better way of doing this. But well... it works.

Comment: NOTE: I had to use `Object.create` on the chunk to copy all its methods as well.